# Restringir template si no estas logueado DJANGO

Tags: django

Hola mi consulta es que si yo estoy en localhost/ y no estas logueado no aparecen los menus, el problema viene cuando yo en la url pongo localhost/prueba accede a prueba y no quiero que se acceda. Alguna solución¿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para proteger un FBV(Vista basada en funciones) se logra haciendo uso del decorador @login_required, aquí un ejemplo:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def mi_view(request):
    return render(request, 'mi_template.html',
                  {'prueba': 'hola mundo'})
```

Espero esto te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Me funciona pero como podria hacer para que no me salga como que no existe, i redirigir al login de nuevo?

Comment: Me gustaria que si no eres staff por ejemplo no puedas acceder a /algo como lo podria hacer? es decir segun permisos que seas puedas acceder o no

Comment: Si quieres validar que sea staff tienes el decorador @staff_member_required  y si quieres proteger mediante un permiso tienes el decorador @permission_required('polls.add_choice', login_url='/loginpage/')

Comment: El @staff_member_required no me sale en decorators.py

Comment: Disculpa, olvide mencionar que se importa de aca: from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

Answer (score 0):

Creo que con LoginRequiredMixin (colocando en la vista que lleva a ese localhost/raiz en tu caso) se hace que no se pueda acceder a una vista o a la plantilla que lo lleva esa vista, si no está logeado.

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class EjemploListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
...
login_url = reverse_lazy('users_app:user-login') #Creo que de esta manera si no está logeado te lleva a donde quieras, en este caso al login.
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "users_app"

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '',
        views.LoginUser.as_view(),
        name='user-login',
    ),
]
```

Comment: Pero eso solo me funciona en Views, si yo hago en una funcion por ejemplo el home def home(request) y hago un return render home.html como le paso el loginrequired

Comment: ¿Quieres que el que no esté logeado no puede ver un contenido concreto? Perdona si no he entendido. Lo digo sino para poder utilizar: if self.request.user.is_authenticated:

Comment: El problema es que cualquier usuario puede acceder a mis urls es decir si no estas logueado en la pagina principal puedes acceder a localhost/documentos o localhost/imagenes yo lo que quiero es que para acceder ahí debes hacer un login previo, si intentas acceder sin login que te haga un reverse a login para que accedas, mi problema es que en las views no tengo todas (View) la mayoria son request